# Canvas drawImage of html5 video works on browsers but not Android

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas, html5-video

Why does this code work on normal browsers, but show the same screenshot for Android browsers?

Html

```
<div class="video">
    <video id="video" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted controls autoplay></video>
</div>
<div class="timeline" id="timeline"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'),
    video = document.getElementById('video'),
    interval = null;

video.addEventListener("playing", onStart);
video.addEventListener("pause", onStop);
video.addEventListener("ended", onEnd);

function onStart() {
    if (interval == null) {
        interval = window.setInterval(createImage, 1000);
    }
}

function onStop() {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}

function onEnd() {
    onStop();
    video.removeEventListener("playing", onStart);
    video.removeEventListener("pause", onStop);
    video.removeEventListener("ended", onEnd);
}

function createImage() {
    console.log('createImage', video.currentTime, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    timeline.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Here is the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/z99cmwtq/6/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas drawImage with video source not working on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436576/html5-canvas-drawimage-with-video-source-not-working-on-android)

Comment: ah yeah, maybe it's an issue with video codec

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still persists on pre-Lollipop devices (<5), for both mp4 and webm videos. Have you been able to fix it / find a workaround?

Comment: Did you try with a webm video? it seems like it could be an issue with video codecs supported by the browser

Answer (score -1):

how come this works for me in chrome android 4.4.4 ?

```
drawImage()
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/kus/pen/aOqvWP)